# How to add administrator privilege in a batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell

while running certain command in windows powershell, it returned with a message " Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.", so in linux (ubuntu) we use 'sudo' right, but how should I do it in windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This code will require admin rights if the batch is not started as admin:

```
net session >nul 2>&1 || (powershell start -verb runas '"%~0"' &exit /b)
```

Comment: or just `runas /user:an_admin_user powershell`